# Electron Ipc render emit event to Vuex

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

Hi guys I'm building an app with multiple windows,

My App is developed in Vue + Electron

The main feature I'm trying to accomplish is when the user for example wants to do some action in electron open popup for example, and next I want to send action to Vuex store to display message to user

So How can I call Vuex action from electron?

Code Sample:

Vue component:

```
import { remote, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

ipcRenderer.send('openPopup', id);
```

Electron Code:

```
import { ipcMain, app } from 'electron';


ipcMain.on('openPopup', (event, args) => {
    console.log('do some action');
    // now how can I call vuex action from here
});
```

I tried calling it with:

```
this.$store
```

but its undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return the desired data back to the renderer process in the ipcMain.on event.

I would also recommend using ipcRenderer.invoke / ipcMain.handle ([Electron Doc - ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener))

```
// Main process
ipcMain.handle('openPopup', async (event, ...args) => {
  const result = await somePromise(...args)
  return result
})

// Renderer process
async () => {
  const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('open-popup', id)
  // this.$store.dispatch(....) etc etc
}
```

Comment: Nice +1, thank you didint know I could do that :)